# Need a delete function in jQuery... Is there any other ajax functions which does the same?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm in need of delete function in jQuery. In jQuery ajax we have `get`, `post`, `put`,  and `delete`. But `PUT` and `DELETE` are not supported by all browsers, so is there any other function which does exactly the same as `DELETE` function?

Comment: POSTing to some code that then deletes something would probably be the most universal.

Comment: ajax functions can do anything... create, read, update and delete + any arbitrary call (is there anything outside of CRUD?)

Answer (score 0):

PUT and DELETE are not supported in HTML forms, but are supported in Ajax requests across all modern browsers.